# How to import an npm module with no available typings?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm attempting to import [this module](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=17&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAr-_X8YPWAhWK4SYKHdf5AkkQFgh4MBA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdthree%2Fvorpal&usg=AFQjCNF_63krPUdx8GlYNpo1s5rDe9FMog), but there are no typings available. What is the mechanism in Typescript that will allow me to "ignore" this module?

I've looked into setting `noImplicitAny` to false, but that doesn't feel like the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `*.d.ts` file and declare your module:

```
// vorpal.d.ts
declare module "vorpal";
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Does this file need to be imported anywhere in particular or would I declare it in the tsconfig file?

Comment: Typically the compiler will pick up the typings automatically, but if you want to specify the folder you can [use the `typeRoots` configuration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types). You don't have to declare the types anywhere, just import the untyped library: `import * as vorpal from "vorpal"`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an (incomplete?) typings file: https://github.com/ahz/vorpal/blob/master/vorpal.d.ts . Maybe you could use that / add on to it to fit your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

For `vorpal` in particular you can find exhaustive typings here: https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/issues/158#issuecomment-364369367

Refer to the comments for further details how to use those particular typings.

Answer (score -1):

```
const vorpal = require('vorpal')
```

Comment: This may provide answer to the question. But please describe answer instead of only code for other users.